"In the strained, yellowy light . . ."
(From A Terrible Kindness by Jo Browning Wroe, Part I, Aberfan, chapter 7)

In the strained , yellowy light from borrowed lamps. Betty groans and rest her hand on the undamaged side of the girl's face. 'All right, Helen,' she whispers, 'Betty's here.'

Wiktionary has this https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/strained. However, I don't really know what the author  is wanting to say there. Maybe it means something like artificial light or dim light or it's a light through a strainer (if something like this exists).

I think any attempts to explain what the author meant can only be guesswork.

I'd say it's the full OED definition 4 - strained - Of conduct, demeanour, gestures, etc.: produced under compulsion or by deliberate effort; artificial, forced, not spontaneous or natural. A very poetic way of pointing out that the light is nothing like broad daylight. This text is hardly a good vehicle for learning English, though, since even most native speakers wouldn't fully understand the metaphor there.

For "light through a strainer", like the sunlight through trees, we'd say "filtered light" (though that could be light through sunglasses), "mottled light", or "dappled light"

When something is strained, it is overextended, doing more than it was meant to do, and not doing it well. I think Kaia is on the right track with "barely able to light up the room".

It could allude to the eyes that are trying to see in the dim light: strained.

There isn't a standard meaning of "strained light". This is literary personification of the light. That means some readers might have slightly different interpretations. The author wants to create a general mood, rather than provide a perfectly clear definition.
In general, it's an analogy with meanings 2 & 3 (from wiktionary):


Under tension; tense.
Not natural or spontaneous but done with effort


If you are feeling strained, you are feeling uneasy, uncomfortable, and tense. You might be struggling with a difficult task, or stuck in an uncomfortable situation. Eyestrain is when your eyes hurt because, for instance, you try to read for too long in dim light. A strained smile is when you smile but it's difficult because you don't feel happy.
So if the light "feels" strained, it might be barely able to light up the room, or the light might make the room feel scary and uncomfortable to be in.
"Yellowy light", by itself, could either mean a dark, scary yellow (first picture), or a warm, cozy yellow (second picture). The first one would be "strained, yellowy light".


